# Python - How to iterate over nested data

Tags: python, nested, hierarchy

I've seen a lot of information on how to iterate over nested data, but none seem to be applicable to my problem - perhaps my method of nesting is not ideal...

I'm working on a web scraping problem to increase the efficiency of my workflow (breaking out and presenting data in a better format than the website provides). I have a class that contains information about a contractor called `ContractorData` that has a property `subs` whcih is a list that contains more `ContractorData` and this nest can continue (each contractor can have sub contractors and those sub contractor can have sub contractors ...)

I have an efficient way to build this hierarchy, but I'm now struggling to find a way to iterate over every contractor down the hierarchy.

```py
class ContractorData():
    def __init__(self, soup:BeautifulSoup, parentId=None):
        self.contractorName = soup.find('a', id=True).getText()
        self.id = int(soup.find('a', id=True).get('href').split('&')[-1].split('=')[1])
        status_options = ['Enrolled', 'Excluded', 'Pending']
        self.status = 'Unknown'
        for i in range(3):
            cls = f'contractorStatusCol{i+1}'
            if 'gray' not in soup.find('div', class_=cls).find('img').get('src'):
                self.status = status_options[i]
                break
        self.date_enrolled = soup.find('div', class_ = 'contractorStatusCol4').get_text().replace(u'\xa0', '')
        self.has_subs = soup.find('a', class_="expand") is not None
        self.subs = []
        self.parent = parentId
```

building the hierarchy: (`general_contractor` is the top of the hierarchy)

```py
def load_subs(pid, cid, level):
    sub_data = {'mode': 'loadEnrollmentCRUD', 'projectId': pid, 'contractorId': cid, 'level':level}
    sub_resp = session.post('https://my-site.com/ajax-contractor.html', data=sub_data)
    sub_soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_resp.text, 'html.parser')
    return [ContractorData(x, cid) for x in sub_soup.find_all('div', class_='contractorStatusCRUD')]

level = 0
has_sub_list = [general_contractor]

while has_sub_list:
    new_sub_list = []
    level = level + 1
    for x in has_sub_list:
        x.subs = load_subs(PROJECT_ID, x.id, level)
        new_sub_list.extend([y for y in x.subs if y.has_subs])
    has_sub_list = new_sub_list
```

I'm thinking to use another while loop like the one I used to build the data, but I can't help but think my data architecture isn't optimal for this type of problem.

Edit based on comments:
The goal is to traverse through all contractors under the `general_contractor` and check their status to see if I need to take action on them.

I did just learn about a recursive function that can call itself which may work for this.

```py
def walk(sub):
    if sub.status != 'Enrolled':
        # handle this case
        pass
    if sub.subs:
        walk(sub.subs)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question? It seems like traversing a *general* contractor and all the subs is  like traversing a tree. Do you want to traverse breadth first or depth first?

Comment: please, add  a minimal sample of your JSON data, with at least 2 nesting levels.

The way it is phrased one will have to revese engineer your code to get the data, to then being able to answer your question.

Comment: Have you considered linked lists? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/ There are natural algorithms to iterate over all elements down the tree of a node (your `ContractorData`) if you use this structure.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you want the results to be displayed if this is a presentation issue or how you want the data stored if this is a data issue?

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies! The data is formed as a nested list, I don't have any JSON to share as I'm working with classes. I did learn about recursive function which I think could work and I added a quick untested example above.

Comment: That's *probably* too much work for `__init__`. Define a *class method* that uses `soup` to find various values to pass to `__init__`, and let `__init__` be as simple as assigning those values to the appropriate attributes.

Comment: I've always been curious about this - is there general guidance as to what to put in the `__init__` function? I've seen some people add functions that just assert a class property that gets called in the `__init__` and never understood why you would want to do that. 
Also, how could a class method pass values into the `__init__` function as that is what get's run first, no?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions to the rescue! I didn't know this was possible, but it's very crisp and clean IMO.

```py
flags = []
def check_subs(contractor:ContractorData):
    if contractor.status == 'Pending': flags.append(contractor)
    for x in contractor.subs:
        check_subs(x)

check_subs(general_contractor)
for c in flags:
    print(f'{c.contractorName}, {c.status}')
```